# Feeding weight maps into a CNN (UNET network) in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have implemented UNET network described in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf)

The network is working fine, but in the paper, they have mentioned adding weighted maps into the network for better boundary separation. The weight maps are calculated this way as far as I understand

```
def unet_weight_map(y, wc=None, w0 = 10, sigma = 5):

"""

Parameters
----------
mask: Numpy array
    2D array of shape (image_height, image_width) representing binary mask
    of objects.
wc: dict
    Dictionary of weight classes.
w0: int
    Border weight parameter.
sigma: int
    Border width parameter.

Returns
-------
Numpy array
    Training weights. A 2D array of shape (image_height, image_width).
"""

labels = label(y)
no_labels = labels == 0
label_ids = sorted(np.unique(labels))[1:]

if len(label_ids) > 1:
    distances = np.zeros((y.shape[0], y.shape[1], len(label_ids)))

    for i, label_id in enumerate(label_ids):
        distances[:,:,i] = distance_transform_edt(labels != label_id)

    distances = np.sort(distances, axis=2)
    d1 = distances[:,:,0]
    d2 = distances[:,:,1]
    w = w0 * np.exp(-1/2*((d1 + d2) / sigma)**2) * no_labels
else:
    w = np.zeros_like(y)
if wc:
    class_weights = np.zeros_like(y)
    for k, v in wc.items():
        class_weights[y == k] = v
    w = w + class_weights
return w
```

Until here everything is fine. But, my question is that how I can get use of these weight maps in the network. I have a weighted binary cross entropy loss defined as below

```
def weighted_binary_crossentropy( y_true, y_pred, weight=[1.,2.]):
y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())
y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())
logloss = -(y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weight[0] + (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred)*weight[1])
return K.mean( logloss, axis=-1)
```

But, here I give the weights as a [a, b] array into the loss for class weights and then feed this loss to the network when compiling. My question is that should I feed those maps into this customized loss function? if so, how? if not, what other way can I use in Keras? Please help. I have read many stack overflow questions related to this problem, but I could not get an answer. I can provide any information regarding my network if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized how to use those maps. First I define an Input (with the same shape as ground truth labels) as the way we define Input when feeding the input images. Something like

```
weights = Input(shape=(shape_of_groundtruth_labels))
```

I define the customized loss with the same structure as wrapper_loss defined above; with weight maps this time, not class weights [1, 2]. Then, when defining the model which needs input and output. I give the input as both input images and input weights. something like:

```
model = Model(inputs=[images, weights], outputs=...)
```

where weights are the one I defined in the Input layer. In the model.compile(), I give the loss as the name of my customized loss (wrapper_loss) with the inputs weights. something like

```
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=wrapper_loss(weight = weights), ...)
```

where the second 'weights' is the one defined in Input layer.
Now, the last thing to do is to do the same in model.fit; I give the weight maps with the images with the same structure as above.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass your own parameters to a custom loss function, you have 2 ways. You should either subclass loss, or use a wrapper function.

For example you can set a wrapper function like this:

```
def wrapper_loss(weights=[1.,2.]):
  def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())
    logloss = -(y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weight[0] + (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred)*weight[1])
    return K.mean(logloss, axis=-1)
  return weighted_binary_crossentropy
```

Then, pass it to the `model.compile()` like this:

```
model.compile(loss=wrapper_loss(weights=[1.,2.]), optimizer=...)
```

P.S: You may need to check these out:

- [tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits)
- [`class_weight` argument for `model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: weighted binary cross entropy I have defined is just to give an array with two values; one for class 0, other for class 1. I pass it directly to the loss function as you mentioned. It is not a problem. My problem is how to get use of those weight maps I mentioned. They are supposed to make pixel wise weights so that weights in boundary sides are higher compared to other regions. Maps are the same lenght and height as the ground truth y's. My problem comes here that I dont know how to do that pixelwise weighting. Do I need to change my weighted crossentropy? If so how? Or what else should I do?